# How to fix a DB probblem in Java (with DERBY DB)?

Tags: java, database, derby

```
 try {
    Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");  
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/gledi", "root", "root");  

     String sql = "SELECT MAX(NR) from ROOT.GLEDI";

     PreparedStatement   pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
     ResultSet   rs = pst.executeQuery();

     if (rs.next()) {

         String nr1= rs.getString("MAX(NR)"); // here is the whole problem !!!!! how   can i fix it 
         text.setText(nr1);
     }  

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```

Comment: Tell us what is happening with this line.

Comment: String nr1 = rs.getString(1);

Answer (score 3):

Give it a name and look it up.

Is that column a String type or a number?

Empty catch blocks are wrong.  Print or log the stack trace.  You'll never know if an exception is thrown otherwise.

Sure you don't want `select count(*) from root.gledi`?  This query looks wrong to me.

You don't close `Connection`, `Statement`, or `ResultSet` in a `finally` block, as you should.

You should encapsulate this code in a method and give it a `Connection`, not create it every time.

So little code, so many errors.

Here's how I might write it:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

/**
 * JdbcDemo 
 * @author Michael
 * @link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21205161/how-to-fix-a-db-probblem-in-java-with-derby-db/21205183#21205183
 * @since 1/18/14 9:51 AM
 */
public class JdbcDemo {
    private static final String SELECT_MAX_ROW_NUMBER = "SELECT MAX(NR) as maxnr from ROOT.GLEDI";

    private Connection connection;

    public JdbcDemo(Connection connection) {
        this.connection = connection;
    }

    public String getMaxRowNumber() {
        String maxRowNumber = "";
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            ps = connection.prepareStatement(SELECT_MAX_ROW_NUMBER);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                maxRowNumber = rs.getString("maxnr");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); // better to log this.
            maxRowNumber = "";
        } finally {
            close(rs);
            close(ps);
        }

        return maxRowNumber;
    }

    // belongs in a database utility class
    public static void close(Statement st) {
        try {
            if (st != null) {
                st.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); // better to log this
        }
    }

    // belongs in a database utility class
    public static void close(ResultSet rs) {
        try {
            if (rs != null) {
                rs.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); // better to log this
        }
    }
}
```